# Doxygen - How to mention the date of the last refactoring?

Tags: doxygen

Is there a good/common way to mention the date of the last refactoring/update/review of a code ?

Expected example:

```
/**
 * \author      Caduchon
 * \brief       Example class
 * \date        April 2016
 * \lastreview  2017-10-09
 */
class Example {};
```

Comment: Won't that information be available from your VCS?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: only for files (for all I know...). Moreover, a review can decide that nothing changes, but the date of the review is updated.

Comment: `git annotate`/`blame` can give you changes by line, e.g. JetBrains IDEs can show these in a sidebar for you. It's not clear what useful information people could gain from *"someone else looked at this in April but decided not to change anything"* - if you're reviewing when things get merged, for example, then the date, author and committer of the merge's commits will be there. Trying to duplicate this information in the code is just asking for it to end up out-of-sync.